# How to tell if component is used as MatFormField

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've just updated a component to implement `MatFormFieldControl` - but I want it to behave and look different if it is not just used as a *regular* control.

So: how to tell if the component is right now used as a `MatFormFieldControl` (inside a `<mat-form-field>`) or just standalone with `ngModel`?

Comment: Would you please tell me what is wrong with this question? So I can maybe adjust it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, for me, is a confused question. A component that implement MatFormFieldControl  (As it's showed in [Creating a custom form field control](https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control)) is made to be used inside a MatFormField. If you want to make a custom form control must implements only ControlValueAccessor (but this is independient your use [(ngModel)] or ReactiveForms) (*)

Well, If you take a look to the constructor of your component, you should see some like

```
constructor(
    private _focusMonitor: FocusMonitor,
    private _elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>,
    @Optional() @Inject(MAT_FORM_FIELD) public _formField: MatFormField,
    @Optional() @Self() public ngControl: NgControl){...}
```

if !_formField is not inside a FormField

```
constructor(..){
   if (!_formField)
      console.log("NOT in form field")
}
```

(*) You can know is a component is "inside" a FormGroup -but if your component is a FormControl alone this not meet your requeriments using

```
constructor(@Optional() @Host() private form: FormGroupDirective){
     if (!form)
       console.log("I'm not inside a FormGroup")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Checking "@Optional() @Inject(MAT_FORM_FIELD) public _formField: MatFormField" is perfectly right!

I don't get the deletion of this question, guess its legit. When displayed as a formfield my control does not need to show its own border. So I need to know if it is used as a FormField. Is something with this assumption wrong?

Comment: The only guess is that only you have thought about a custom MatFormControl that can be used outside of a MatFormField (I love your idea, but there must be people who don't understand it, or not has very knowledge about Angular :))